# How to change post thumbnail size in home page

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I would like to change the size of post thumbnails in **my home page in mobile view**. I did it on desktop and tablet but I can't do it on mobile. My website is www.aytepignosi.com . The thumbnails now are too small as you can see in the screenshot. I would like to make them as they are in desktop view, that means: the image centered and automatically resized accordinglly to screen size. The CSS I used for desktop is:

```
.post-body img {
width:100%;
height:100%;
display: block;
}
```

And also if this could apply to post titles, again **only for home page in mobile view**. When I open a post all seem to be ok.
Thank you in advance.
(I use blogger)
[image: screenshot of home page posts]

This is the html of the image of the most recent post:

```
<div class="separator" style="clear: both; text-align: center;">
<a href="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-b_CL20DIHaY/Xn9AAIf_hBI/AAAAAAAAIc0/LIgULtr32mcItRO67cQ9NMJDyegolowwQCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/%25CE%25B5%25CE%25BA%25CF%2587%25CE%25B1%25CF%2581%25CF%2584%2B%25CF%2584%25CE%25BF%25CE%25BB%25CE%25BB%25CE%25B5%2B%25CF%2580%25CE%25B1%25CE%25BD%25CE%25B4%25CE%25B7%25CE%25BC%25CE%25B9%25CE%25B1%2B2%2B%25282%2529.png" imageanchor="1" style="clear: left; float: left; margin-bottom: 1em; margin-right: 1em;"><img border="0" data-original-height="644" data-original-width="1145" height="111" src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-b_CL20DIHaY/Xn9AAIf_hBI/AAAAAAAAIc0/LIgULtr32mcItRO67cQ9NMJDyegolowwQCLcBGAsYHQ/s1600/%25CE%25B5%25CE%25BA%25CF%2587%25CE%25B1%25CF%2581%25CF%2584%2B%25CF%2584%25CE%25BF%25CE%25BB%25CE%25BB%25CE%25B5%2B%25CF%2580%25CE%25B1%25CE%25BD%25CE%25B4%25CE%25B7%25CE%25BC%25CE%25B9%25CE%25B1%2B2%2B%25282%2529.png" width="200" /></a></div>
```

[image]

Comment: "`I can't do it on mobile`" - are you using media queries? If not, look up media queries. Specify a desired width for each screen size in your mobile media queries, and set the height to auto (so that the image is not skewed). Good luck

Comment: I don't know at all what media queries are. Can you be more specific please?

Comment: Type in media queries in stackoverflow and read the tag description. It's fall asleep time here.

Comment: I don't understand what to do. I read a little bit but I have no idea where to start from. I suppose I need a css code to do this. How can I use a media query? Sorry I'm not that familiar with writing code. I can do basic stuff. I would like someone to be a little bit more specific. Thanks.

Comment: Please can someone help me with my issue?

Comment: Look at the following question answers to get some tips on media queries: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60518193/1675954) , [two](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31597187/1675954), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52129700/1675954). Also if you click on the media-queries tag you'll get lots of related questions/answers. Plus use google to search for info on media queries. All the best.

Comment: @NikosBatras see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this CSS code in your CSS file:

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
    .mobile-index-title{
        width:100%;
    }

    .post-body img, .post-body .tr-caption-container, .Profile img, .Image img, .BlogList .item-thumbnail img{
        max-width:100%;
    }

    .mobile-index-thumbnail{
        float:none;
        text-align:center;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Elman Huseynov. I used your code. The title is fixed, the thumbnails are centered but they are still too small. Their size didn't change. I wish I could upload here a screenshot so you can see. So the size remains to fix.

Comment: @NikosBatras the sizes of images are also small on desktop devices, that is why, it is the same on mobile. Give me a link where images are big on desktop, I will update my code to make it small on mobile devices then.

Comment: Thank you. My website is www.aytepignosi.com. Images on desktop are not small.

Comment: @NikosBatras the images that are on your screenshot are in the sidebar, which is also small images on desktop.

Comment: No, the images on the screenshot are not in the sidebar. They are in the main central area of the website. These are my posts that I update daily, not the sidebar. The sidebar in desktop is on the left side and in mobile view is toward the end as you scroll down.

Comment: @NikosBatras Then on mobile I can see your posts with big image sizes (360x 240)

Comment: Not in home page, right? To me, in home page images of posts are very small.

Comment: @NikosBatras I can see them on homege mobile version big as well. Only sidebar images are small there.

Comment: You are looking at the wrong images. On home page just scroll a little bit from the top, just below the first adsense ad. Images there are very small. You are refering to the images of sidebar which is toward the end of the home page (and each page) as you scroll down.

Comment: then you need to change your code to load the images with original sizes. At this moment on mobile version you loaded the images with the same size as in sidebar of the desktop version. There is nothing to do with HTML css, you just need to load images with the same URL as you did on desktop devices.

Comment: I don't change the url when I post a new post. The image is the same for desktop and mobile.

Comment: @NikosBatras can you update your question by showing HTML of the images URL and sreen of it please?

Comment: I added the html and a screenshot.

Comment: Can you please help me a little bit more? I added the html and a screenshot. Thank you.

Comment: @NikosBatras I dont find big html images on moble.

Comment: I even do not see them on mobile

Comment: do you have skype?